# is there command line software for convert jpg to png In addition to imagemagick in linux?

Tags: linux, images, image-processing, png, jpg

I have issues with imagemagick on my machine, and hence am looking for an alternative that can be used to convert images from JPEG to PNG on the command line. The tool must run on Linux, and preferably should be available for free.

Comment: What is the issue with imagemagick that you need something "in addition"? Your question body doesn't tell.

Comment: I install imagemagick but I have a problems whit jpg convert with library version

Comment: If you need help solving issues with software you're using, SR isn't the right place ([SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) might be, but they would need much more details as well). If you are looking for alternative software, please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) We cannot recommend anything if we don't know what you need.

Comment: I use graphicsmagick for complete this task

Comment: Thanks for self-answering, Alejandro. I've edited your question to give you an example how the body should look like to *not* get it closed as being unclear. Enjoy your solution – and please take care for the body of your questions ;)

Comment: If it does not have to be CLI software there is [XnConvert](http://www.xnview.com/de/xnconvert/) that does the job.

Comment: Hum. Why do you need to do that? You only will use more disk space. I see no additional benefit.

Answer (score 1):

With `convert`:

```
ls -1 *.jpg | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'convert "$0" "${0%.jpg}.png"'
```

with `mogrify` (note that is part of imagemagick, but could work yor you):

```
mogrify -format png /path/*.jpg
```

With `parallel`:

```
parallel convert '{}' '{.}.png' ::: *.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I used *graphicsmagick* to complete this task. To install it on Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dhor/myway
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
```

Converting an image then can be done as follows:

```
gm convert input.jpg output.png
```

Comment: Actually multiple repositories and installing software without using the system apackage manager are the key to breaking system apps. The only way imagemagick can fail due to library versions in a Ubuntu system is by doing something like that (configuring a rogue PPA for example)

Comment: @jsbueno, Re "*a rogue PPA*": Please clarify whether you believe `ppa:dhor/myway` to actually be a **rogue** PPA, (*i.e.* infected or harmful), or if you're merely offering general words of caution.

Comment: Just general words of caution. As later in 2016, I managed to all but wipe out my system by just putting a PPA which was badly configured and replaced some packages it should not have.